# replace one column with another using regex matching in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I am working with some survey data and I would like to replace the contents of one survey item/column with another survey item, while keeping original cell contents. Ex - replace Q2_1.x with Q2_1.y if Q2_1.x is missing.

**Here is an example of my data:**

```
org_dat <- read_table('ID   Q2_1.x  Q2_2.x  Q2_1.y  Q2_2.y  Q14_1.x Q14_1.y Q15
1   Yes NA  NA  NA  Sometimes   NA  NA
2   -99 NA  No  NA  NA  Always  Yes
3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4   NA  NA  NA  No  NA  NA  No 
5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  Always  NA
6   NA  NA  NA  No  NA  NA  NA') %>% mutate_all(as.character)
```

**Here is my desired output:**

```
dat_out <- read_table('ID   Q2_1    Q2_2    Q14_1   Q15
1   Yes NA  Sometimes   NA
2   No  NA  Always  Yes
3   NA  NA  NA  NA
4   NA  No  NA  No
5   NA  NA  Always  NA
6   NA  No  NA  NA')
```

**Current solution**
I know that I can replace each of these columns individually, but I have a lot of columns to deal with and I would like to use a smart dplyr/grepl way of solving this! Any ideas? It is always the case that I am replacing the Q*.x with the Q*.y.

```
org_dat %>% mutate(Q2_1.x = case_when(is.na(Q2_1.x) ~ Q2_1.y,
                                TRUE ~ Q2_1.x)) %>% 
       mutate(Q2_2.x = case_when(is.na(Q2_2.x) ~ Q2_2.y,
                                TRUE ~ Q2_2.x)) %>%
  mutate(Q14_1.x = case_when(is.na(Q14_1.x) ~ Q14_1.y,
                            TRUE ~ Q14_1.x)) %>%
  rename(Q2_1 = Q2_1.x,
         Q2_2 = Q2_2.x,
         Q14_1 = Q14_1.x) %>%
  select(-matches("x|y"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `across` and `coalesce`, loop `across` the columns that `ends_with` 'x', replace (`str_replace`) the substring in column name (`cur_column()`) from 'x' to 'y', `get` the column value, do `coalesce` with the looped column, and subsequently, remove the substring from column name in `.names`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
org_dat %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with("x"),
     ~ coalesce(., get(str_replace(cur_column(), "x", "y"))),
        .names = "{str_remove(.col, '.x')}"), .keep = "unused", .before = 2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  ID    Q2_1  Q2_2  Q14_1     Q15  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 1     Yes   <NA>  Sometimes <NA> 
2 2     No    <NA>  Always    Yes  
3 3     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      <NA> 
4 4     <NA>  No    <NA>      No   
5 5     <NA>  <NA>  Always    <NA> 
6 6     <NA>  No    <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: wow-- this is so elegant. How does coalesce know to only look at those matching columns (Q2_1.x and Q2_1.y)?

Comment: @NewBee the loop is only looping `across` the ".x" columns.  Inside the loop, the column name (`cur_column()`) `.x` is changed to `.y`, and `get` the corresponding value of that column

Comment: TY! also is there a way to return all the columns that are not touched by the loop without explicitly calling them (Q15). I have a lot of columns like this that should return as they are..

Comment: @NewBee updated the post

Comment: @NewBee I think the `mutate` step with `.keep` and `.before` should fix that issue as in the update

Comment: so sorry, I was wondering how to modify your code if I wanted the .y cols to replace the .x columns regardless of whether the .x cols was NA or not NA??

Comment: @NewBee it is not clear. Can you post as a new question. thanks.  Perhaps, `case_when(.x == 'someval' ~ get(str_replace(cur_column(), "x", "y")), TRUE ~ .x)`

Comment: it's a small change from my OP! Example; if Q2_1.x = "-99", I want to replace that cell with Q2_1.y = "Yes" to make Q2_1 = "Yes".  In the current solution Q2_1.x only gets replaced with Q2_1.y IF Q2_1.x = NA.

Comment: You can use `case_when`. Do you want to return all the columns i.e. .x and .y or just a single column without the .x or .y

Comment: all the column is fine, I can clean that out later

Comment: then loop over the `.y` columns, get the `.x` and use `case_when` i.e. `org_dat %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with(".y"),
     ~case_when(get(str_replace(cur_column(), "y", "x")) == -99 ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ .x)))`

Comment: that's not quite what I mean, the 'yes' was only an example. So Q2_1.x should take on Q2_1.y cell value without being explicitly stated in the case_when statement as ~"yes".

Comment: @NewBee Then, you can use `coalesce` or `replace` or `case_when` i.e. ` ~{tmp <- get(str_replace(cur_column(), "y", "x")); case_when(tmp == -99 ~  tmp,TRUE ~ .x)))`

Comment: in the context of my data ( I snuck in on -99 into my org_dat) I tried "org_dat %>% mutate(across(ends_with("x"), ~{tmp <- get(str_replace(cur_column(), "y", "x")); case_when(tmp == -99 ~ tmp,TRUE ~ .x)))" but I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: @NewBee can you post as a new question as it is not clear where you are wrong